Launching react native || error at startup
I encountered a problem when launching a project on react native.
This project is at my colleagues, it launches, but not at mine.
What did I do?:
I wrote dependencies in the account parameters.
Downloaded Android studio, installed all the settings as my colleagues.
Downloaded java, gradle, tried all ideas, but unfortunately it didn't help
I set up android studio (when I launch the project, the emulator doesn't see the device), when I connect the device via USB, the project sees it.
My colleagues have everything running, but I don't.
Error code:
Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:
expo-constants, expo-file-system

Configure project :react-native-honeywell-barcode-reader
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.33.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.33.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.33.1.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.speedata:deivice:1.5.5.
Required by:
project :app
Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0.
Required by:
project :app > project :expo-image-picker


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
enter image description here
BUILD FAILED in 32s


error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
